# How to repeat a part of a formula in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following formula `=(((C3*B3%)+(C4*B4%))*100)/C1`: instead of repeat the part `((C3*B3%)+(C4*B4%))` for every next cells (e.g: `((C3*B3%)+(C4*B4%)+(C5*B5%)+(C6*B6%))` ), is there a way to write this for a range of indexes?

Comment: could you add an extract of some data and or context?

Comment: Have you tried dragging the appropriate ranges inside the, then array, formula when writing it?

Comment: Also search for Sumproduct

Comment: From [here](https://www.udrop.com/6Qy2/Test.xlsx?download_token=8702f20f4b5cba268e69d63bb3582f8e3c5c5c375a43f45214d2da1f93219c8e) you can download a sample: I would like to be able to add "Fixed yield" so that the composite yeld in B1 recalculate automatically.

Comment: Are you asking about algebra: A(B+C) : AB + AC ??

Comment: Thanks. I strongly suspect you can create what you need with `INDEX` and `SEQUENCE` but I don't understand your context enough to build a quick test. Will you be adding more rows under 3&4 in your example? Will you know how many? Do you only need one result or to build a series as a column or row?

Comment: I would like to insert infinite rows. Now I tried with the formula `=((SUMPRODUCT((C3:C999999),(B3:B999999)))*100)/C1` and I obtain something near I want to realize: in this case I must divide by 100 the values in the column B. The problem now is that the values in the column B are percentage and I would like to mantain the format. Could you post a solution with `INDEX` and `SEQUENCE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`=100*SUMPRODUCT(C3:C999999,B3:B999999%)/C1`